# Possible causes of an incomplete file generated from a C++ program

Tags: c++, string, overflow, stringstream

I have a large program which contains a section that generates data in an output file.

The problem is that it sometimes (inconsistently) generates the output file truncated at a certain number of lines. And sometimes it generates the complete file without any problem.

When the complete file is generated it has around 1,700,000 lines.
And when the file is truncated it has around 1,645,237 lines. Always that number of lines.

When it does generate a truncated file it does not give me any error like a segmentation fault or something. It just finishes execution and the file is generated having missing data.

Since it does not generate an error I crossed out the possibility of having a stringstream or string overflow.

Are there other causes that I should look up for?

The following is an example of how the file generation section works:

```
void generateSection1(output){
    string section_1 = getSection1();
    output << section_1;
}
void generateSection2(output){
    string section_2 = getSection2();
    output << section_2;
}
void generateSection3(output){
    string section_3 = getSection3();
    output << section_3;
}
void writeFile(string filename){

    stringstream output;
    
    output << "START" << endl;
    generateSection1(output);
    generateSection2(output);
    generateSection3(output);
    
    output << "FINISH" << endl;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (filename);
    myfile << output;
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the list of possible C++ bugs, in any C++ progam, is going to be a very, very large list. It is unlikely that anyone on Stackoverflow will be able to tell you anything without a [mre].

Comment: From this it is impossible to tell what the issue might be. You can add headers/footers to `generateSection` so that you can find them in the file, and see which one of them is truncated, but there is no way to help fix a code/problem we can't see